# Understanding Symbols in Chomsky's *Logical Structure of Linguistic Theory*

Tags: syntax, chomsky, logic

I've been reading Chomsky's *The Logical Structure of Linguistic Theory*, and have come up rather suddenly against a stumbling block. On page 133, he uses without explanation some notation that's unfamiliar to me. I've included an image because I couldn't figure out how to format the superscript & multiple subscripts together. I'm willing to do the work to understand this: I don't need someone to spell it out for me. I've figured out that ∈ and ⊂ are from set theory, and I've begun doing some reading on set theory. (The meaning of those two symbols, specifically, is easy enough, & it doesn't seem like I need much set theory to understand what he's saying here.) But I can't figure out what's going on with the italic, non-cursive capital C with both the superscript and subscript letters. How do I figure out the relationship between n and nᵢ? What should I be reading? I'm assuming that the lowercase and capital n/N have some standard relationship. What should I be looking into to understand that?

[image: image of a segment of p 133 of LSLT]

Once again, I'm very willing to do the reading myself. I've been Googling things like (Chomsky "set theory" symbols) and (Chomsky logic "set theory"), but no dice, as yet. I just need to be set in the right direction.

Much thanks for any help.

Comment: I suppose I should add that I have a speculative reading of this, in which it's not a prior symbolic system but Chomsky's shorthand which is a little underexplained for a reader like me: Each ⁿ is an order; each nᵢ is a category within that order. N is the total number of orders. aₙ is the total number of categories in any order n. Thus a₁ > a₂ > … > a<sub>N</sub> makes sense, as there should be fewer categories on higher orders. The arrows ⇒ just point to explanations of symbols in the previous comments. I'm dissatisfied with this explanation because I'm basing it entirely on speculation.

Comment: Capital C with superscript *a* and subscript *b* is the number of combinations of *a* things taken *b* at a time.

Comment: Looking at the quote, I can't make sense of much.  Consider condition (iv).  It seems to say that a certain set is a proper subset of a certain other set only when the two sets are the same.  But a set is never a proper subset of itself.  So, ...??

Comment: Historically, $\subset$ was not consistently used for proper subset, and Chomsky for sure didn't follow that convention in the 70s.  So it just means modern $\subseteq$ here.

Comment: The arrows are almost certainly logical implication; (iii) just says all elements of $C^n_n_i$ are words, (iv) implies that no class is a subset of another with the same $n$. Word classes ought to refer to parts of speech I think, but I have no idea what he's doing with $n$, $n_i$, and $a_n$.